# How do I get a Datastore Entity by its unique ID if I know the ID?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

This is how I created the entities

```
Key reviewsKey = KeyFactory.createKey("Reviews", "Reviews");        
Entity reviewEntity = new Entity("aReview", reviewsKey);
....
```

This is how I am trying to get an entity by its key

```
Key key = KeyFactory.createKey("Reviews", "Reviews");
Entity reviewEntity = datastore.get(key.getChild("aReview", reviewId));
....
```

I know there is an entity with key = 14 but i keep getting an exception that there is no entity found

> Reviews("Reviews")/aReview("14")

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was it was looking for a string ID when it should have been Long

I have parsed it to Long and it works now.

```
Key key = KeyFactory.createKey("Reviews", "Reviews");
Entity reviewEntity = datastore.get(key.getChild("aReview", Long.parseLong(reviewId)));
```